# g_source_set_callback : invalid callback data pointer

Tags: c, linux, glib

using Glib, I created two GSource and registered the same callback function.

and, pass different data pointers to each GSource.

code is below...

```
gboolean cb (gpointer data)
{
    printf("data is %d \n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(data));
}

void init_g_source (void)
{
    GSource* src1 = g_timeout_source_new (1000);
    g_source_set_callback (src1, cb, GINT_TO_POINTER(9), NULL);
    g_source_attach (src1, g_main_loop_get_context(mainloop));            
    g_source_unref (src1);

    GIOChannel *ch = g_io_channel_unix_new (socket_fd);        
    GSource* src2 = g_io_create_watch (ch, G_IO_IN);    
    g_source_set_callback (src2, cb, GINT_TO_POINTER(7), NULL);
    g_source_attach (src2, g_main_loop_get_context(mainloop));            
    g_source_unref (src2);  
}
```

Expected results

- when src1 callback : data is 9
- when src2 callback : data is 7

However, actual results

- when src1 callback : data is 9
- when src2 callback : data is 6811792

Why is the wrong data pointer only in src2 using socket_fd?

1. Passed a pointer to a local or global variable
   : result is the same.
2. Passed a pointer to memory allocation (g_malloc or g_new)
   : result is the same.
3. Passed a NULL pointer
   : Only the values are different, but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried to  `int data = 9; g_source_set_callback (src1, cb, &data, NULL);` ?

Comment: Passed a pointer to a local or global variable, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GSource` created by `g_io_create_watch()` runs callback functions of type `GIOFunc`, not `GSourceFunc`. (This is explained in the documentation for [`g_io_add_watch()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch), but not mentioned in the documentation for `g_io_create_watch()`.)

You need different callback functions for the two `GSource`s:

```
gboolean cb (gpointer data)
{
    printf("data is %d \n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(data));
}

gboolean cb_io (GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data)
{
    printf("data is %d \n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(data));
}

void init_g_source (void)
{
    GSource* src1 = g_timeout_source_new (1000);
    g_source_set_callback (src1, cb, GINT_TO_POINTER(9), NULL);
    g_source_attach (src1, g_main_loop_get_context(mainloop));            
    g_source_unref (src1);

    GIOChannel *ch = g_io_channel_unix_new (socket_fd);        
    GSource* src2 = g_io_create_watch (ch, G_IO_IN);    
    g_source_set_callback (src2, G_SOURCE_FUNC (cb_io), GINT_TO_POINTER(7), NULL);
    g_source_attach (src2, g_main_loop_get_context(mainloop));            
    g_source_unref (src2);  
}
```